# Writing a function that incrementally scans an area on a grid in a circular fashion

Tags: python, performance, geometry

The problem is that there is a 2 dimensional grid system with an arbitrary number of specified dots (x,y). Another dot is then provided and the specified dot that is the closest to the provided dot needs to be returned. Since the number of specified dots is very large it is not efficient to iterate over all of them, it would be more efficient to individually look up if points inside the grid that are close to the provided dot.

In practice, I am using pygame to display different kind of pictures and would like to calculate the distance between the cursor location and the closest dot that is not white.

My initial solution was to write a function that incrementally scans the area around the cursor in a circular manner until a non-white dot is found. The function would first take in `0` and e.g. `(10,10)` (the current position as arguments) and scan the first layer of what would make up the cicle that is slowly growing outwards. (in this case it would look up `(9,10),(10,9),(11,10),(10,11)`). If no colored dot was found it would be called again with `1` and `(10,10)` and scan the dots `(8,10),(9,9),(10,8),(11,9),(12,10),(11,11),(10,12),(10,12)`. I would slowly increase the radius and use the pythagorean theorem to assert whether a dot is within the current radius or not. Obviously the same dot shouldn't be scanned twice, in my current solution I would simply store the already scanned values and make sure they are not scanned again.

Since this function would scale poorly and would take up a lot of resources if called frequently I wanted to ask if there was a better way of solving this problem.

Another solution I thought of was to scan the area around the cursor in a squared manner, and if a dot is found, the function will keep scanning the remaining area that would make up a circle to see if there is a dot that is yet closer than the one found in the square. That way no lookup for already scanned pixels needs to be made.

Would this solution be more efficient? Does it depend on the likelyhood of how far away a dot could be in the end? For this purpose it is unlikely that the next colored dot is more than 200 pixels away, but how would it look for a different case?

Comment: These might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: You could maintain a K-d tree of the non-white pixels, then lookups are expected O(log n) time

Comment: @Dennis That would work, but in case the pixels on the screen start moving I would need to generate this tree for every new frame. I think in the case of pygame scanning every pixel on the screen uses up a lot of resources, but it's also resource intensive to scan the area around the cursor first. Do you think your solution would still be more efficient than this?

Comment: I think a K-d tree might still work: assuming the screen moves continuously, you could have a "logical" grid that doesn't move between frames but then have a "physical" grid of what is currently shown on the screen. You can have a K-d tree on the logical grid, but as pixels of the logical grid enter and leave the physical grid, you can add and remove them from the K-d tree accordingly.

Comment: How many point here is in practice? What is a typical size for the grid? Are the point generally evenly distributed or there is no guarantee about this?

Comment: @JérômeRichard The distribution of the points is arbitrary, you can imagine it like an old gba game where the pixels represent the game. in practice there are probably between 5000-10000 colored pixels at all times in a grid of 800x600, although this size may increase in the future.

Answer (score 0):

One efficient strategy is to use a **multi-level grid**. The idea is to aggregate the dots in cells of a grid with a smaller size so that each cell of the grid match with a bloc of pixel (eg. 32x32) in the big grid. This strategy speed up the case where there is no dots near the cursor. If there is a dot near the cursor, then the solution can be quickly found in most of the case. However, this solution does not help of a lot of dots are almost-all massively-packed near the cursor. If dots often moves, you certainly need to fully update the grid (in `O(Ndots)` time). Otherwise, you can move dots between cells (and use a set data structure to efficiently do that). *Numpy* can help a lot to speed up such computation (and possibly Cython or Numba regarding your performance needs).

An alternative solution is to use a [**quad-tree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). This solution have a good worst-case running time because it efficiently subdivides the space where there are more dots. However, building a quad-tree from a Python code is a bit expensive and it only worth it of dots do not move too much between frames (a partial update can be used otherwise like in the previous strategy). Note that [SciPy implements a K-d tree data structure](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html).

In your case, I expect the multi-level grid with full updates to be the fastest for your needs because the number of dots is relatively small and I guess dots cannot overlap. If the number of fetch per frame is small, a simple loop over the dots should even be faster assuming Numpy/Numba/Cython are used to do that (and the loop is optimized not to use a square root).

Comment: I have implemented your solution and made a post about it here if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70705629/calculating-the-nearest-neighbour-of-a-dot-in-a-2d-grid-by-using-a-multilevel-gr